# Using MySql, can I sort a column but have 0 come last?

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-order-by

I want to sort by an column of ints ascending, but I want 0 to come last. Is there anyway to do this in MySql?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

You may want to try the following:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table ORDER BY your_field = 0, your_field;
```

Test case:

```
CREATE TABLE list (a int);

INSERT INTO list VALUES (0);
INSERT INTO list VALUES (0);
INSERT INTO list VALUES (0);
INSERT INTO list VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO list VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO list VALUES (3);
INSERT INTO list VALUES (4);
INSERT INTO list VALUES (5);
```

Result:

```
SELECT * FROM list ORDER BY a = 0, a;

+------+
| a    |
+------+
|    1 |
|    2 |
|    3 |
|    4 |
|    5 |
|    0 |
|    0 |
|    0 |
+------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: can you put any boolean condition with the ORDER BY ?

Comment: @JSmaga: You can use any expression. See the `ORDER BY` [syntax here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html): `[ORDER BY {col_name | expr | position}`

Comment: Thanks alot. Superb

Comment: How to get this result in MS SQL query?

Comment: @Daniel Vassallo It's nice. But what it says? and How it works?

Comment: @DanielVassallo This sure does work. But what is the principle behind this working ?

Comment: @DanielVassallo it's work. But how it work with limit?

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following:

```
SELECT value, IF (value = 0, NULL, value) as sort_order
FROM table
ORDER BY sort_order DESC
```

Null values will be down of the list.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM your_table ORDER BY 0.1/your_field;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query should do the trick.

```
(SELECT * FROM table WHERE num!=0 ORDER BY num) UNION (SELECT * FROM table WHERE num=0)
```