# Order by Maximum condition match

Tags: sql, select, sql-order-by, where-clause

Please help me to create a select query which contains 10 'where' clause and the order should be like that:
the results should be displayed in order of most keywords(where conditions) matched down to least matched.

NOTE: all 10 condition are with "OR".

Please help me to create this query.
i am using ms-sql server 2005

Like:

```
Select *
  from employee
 where empid in (1,2,4,332,434)
    or empname like 'raj%'
    or city = 'jodhpur'
    or salary >5000
```

In above query all those record which matches maximum conditions should be on top and less matching condition record should be at bottom.

Comment: Can you give an example of the query you are using?

Comment: Some sample schema would be helpful.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT (CASE WHEN cond1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
                CASE WHEN cond2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
                CASE WHEN cond2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
                ...
                CASE WHEN cond10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
               ) AS numMatches,
               other_columns...
          FROM mytable
       ) xxx
 WHERE numMatches > 0
 ORDER BY numMatches DESC
```

Comment: looks great, i have no idea how to do this with doctrine + symfony :D

Comment: This needs to be in SQL textbooks.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** This answer was posted before the question was modified with a concrete example. [Marcelo's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289095/order-by-maximum-condition-match/3289152#3289152) addresses the actual problem. On the other hand, my answer was giving priority to matches of specific fields.

---

You may want to try something like the following, using the same expressions in the `ORDER BY` clause as in your `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT    *
FROM      your_table
WHERE     field_1 = 100 OR
          field_2 = 200 OR
          field_3 = 300
ORDER BY  field_1 = 100 DESC,
          field_2 = 200 DESC,
          field_3 = 300 DESC;
```

I've recently answered a similar question on Stack Overflow which you might be interested in checking out:

- [Is there a SQL technique for ordering by matching multiple criteria?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162170/is-there-a-sql-technique-for-ordering-by-matching-multiple-criteria)

Comment: This doesn't order according to the number of matches.

Comment: Yes it's true. It wasn't clear in the original question... I'm trying to see if I can adapt my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are many options/answers possible. Best answer depends on size of the data, non-functional requirements, etc.

That said, what I would do is something like this (easy to read / debug):

```
  Select * from 
    (Select *, iif(condition1 = bla, 1, 0) as match1, ..... , match1+match2...+match10 as totalmatchscore from sourcetable
    where 
      condition1 = bla or
      condition2 = bla2
      ....) as helperquery
    order by helperquery.totalmatchscore desc
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not get this to work for me on Oracle.
If using oracle, then this [Order by Maximum condition match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289095/order-by-maximum-condition-match) is a good solution.
Utilizes the case when language feature