# double sorted selection from a single table

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table with an id as the primary key, and a description as another field.

I want to first select the records that have the id<=4, sorted by description, then I want all the other records (id>4), sorted by description. Can't get there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use an `id <= 4` expression in your `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table ORDER BY id <= 4 DESC, description;
```

Test case (using MySQL):

```
CREATE TABLE your_table (id int, description varchar(50));

INSERT INTO your_table VALUES (1, 'c');
INSERT INTO your_table VALUES (2, 'a');
INSERT INTO your_table VALUES (3, 'z');
INSERT INTO your_table VALUES (4, 'b');
INSERT INTO your_table VALUES (5, 'g');
INSERT INTO your_table VALUES (6, 'o');
INSERT INTO your_table VALUES (7, 'c');
INSERT INTO your_table VALUES (8, 'p');
```

Result:

```
+------+-------------+
| id   | description |
+------+-------------+
|    2 | a           |
|    4 | b           |
|    1 | c           |
|    3 | z           |
|    7 | c           |
|    5 | g           |
|    6 | o           |
|    8 | p           |
+------+-------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

Related post:

- [Using MySql, can I sort a column but have 0 come last?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130197/using-mysql-can-i-sort-a-column-but-have-0-come-last)

Answer (score 4):

```
select id, descr
from t
order by 
 case when id <= 4 then 0 else 1 end, 
 descr
```

Comment: +1 I like this, my first thought for stuff like this is always UNION instead of thinking of the slicker solution.

Comment: Why not just `ORDER BY id <= 4 DESC, descr`? ... The comparison operators already return `0` or `1`.

Comment: @Daniel: Because initially OP didn't say anything about the database. This trick might be valid in mysql (I believe it's an extension?), but, for instance, in MS SQL Server the result of a comparison is a boolean value which cannot be used this way, therefore a `case` is a must.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I see that the `[mysql]` tag was added later. Yes it won't work in SQL Server, but in MySQL, the `ORDER BY` syntax allows any valid expression... Anyway +1 as yours is more portable.

Answer (score 2):

```
select *, id<=4 as low from table order by low, description
```

Comment: This is fine, even if it returns a not-needed column (low)

Answer (score 1):

```
select id, description
from MyTable
order by case when id <= 4 then 0 else 1 end, description
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UNION`

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id <=4 ORDER by description)aaa
UNION
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id >4 ORDER by description)bbb
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM table1
ORDER BY
CASE WHEN id <=4 THEN 0
ELSE 1
END, description
```

Comment: the first one doesn't work because of the ORDER BY before the UNION (MySQl). second one is fine.

Comment: Oops, my bad.. Union version fixed.