# Sorting zeros last with Flask / SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a bunch of objects with a numeric rank, zero meaning "unranked". I'd like to be able to sort by number first and have zeros be last, like:

```
1 2 3 0 0 0
```

If I do `order_by(Page.rank.asc())` I get:

```
0 0 0 1 2 3
```

If I do `order_by(Page.rank.desc())` I get:

```
3 2 1 0 0 0
```

I'm looking to be able to do this: [Using MySql, can I sort a column but have 0 come last?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130197/using-mysql-can-i-sort-a-column-but-have-0-come-last) using SQLAlchemy in Flask.

Comment: What if you do `order_by(Page.rank=0, Page.rank)` as suggested in the link you indicate?

Comment: Returns "SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression"

Comment: Maybe it is `Page.rank==0`, I always get confused with the comparison conditions in SQLAlchemy.

Comment: Thank you @fedorqui! Works. Submit that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As we discovered together in the comments, this can make it:

```
order_by(Page.rank==0, Page.rank)
```

(Still amazed about the great solution it was given in the link you provided).